# C# System.Data.EvaluateException: 'Cannot perform 'Like' operation on System.Int64 and System.String.' I'm looking for a solution to your error please

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

This method works when I enter text in the text box.However, when the "else if" block runs, it gives an error that I specified in the header.What can I do to solve this?
The problem happens only in the "else if" block. This problem doesn't work in other if,else etc. blocks.

```
        private void txt_box_urun_ara_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (urun_isim_radio.Checked == true)
        {
            (tablo_urunler.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("UrunAdi LIKE '{0}%'", txt_box_urun_ara.Text);
        }
        else if (urun_id_radio.Checked == true)
        {
            (tablo_urunler.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("UrunID LIKE '{0}%'", txt_box_urun_ara.Text);
        }
        else {
            urun_isim_radio.Checked = true;
            (tablo_urunler.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("UrunAdi LIKE '{0}%'", txt_box_urun_ara.Text);

        }
```

Comment: Presumably `UrunID` is an integer, but something in quotes is a string. So you're doing `UrunID LIKE '3'`, when you should be doing `UrunID LIKE 3` (note the lack of quotes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, I reproduced your problem. We can use `Convert(ID, System.String) LIKE` to perform the like operation about int type.

I make a code example and you can refer to it.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(radioButton1.Checked==true)
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert(Adi, System.String) LIKE '{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
        }
        else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Convert(ID, System.String) LIKE '{0}%'",textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
   
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Adi", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Rows.Add(123,1001);
        dt.Rows.Add(124,1002);
        dt.Rows.Add(125, 1003);
        dt.Rows.Add(135, 1004);
        dt.Rows.Add(167, 1101);
        dt.Rows.Add(196, 1102);
        dt.Rows.Add(193, 1103);
        dt.Rows.Add(186, 1104);
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Result:

[image]